# passing integer value in string format to POST method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am new to IOS i created textfield with named as (value1) and string as (fourthstr).when user enter integer value in textfield that value can be stored in string and finally that string can be passed as parameter for POST method.

Coding:
viewdidload

```
fourthstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value1.text];
```

but the string not passing to the post method.

*Post method:*

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{


    NSData *postData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[str length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){

        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

*picker view delegates:*

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag ==2){
    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
        branchid1 = (NSString *)[arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row];

        NSLog([arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row]);

    }else if(pickerView.tag ==1){
    currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
        currencyid1 = (NSString *)[id1 objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([id1 objectAtIndex:row]);


    }
    else
    {
        currency2.text = (NSString *)[from_currency objectAtIndex:row];
        currencyid2 = (NSString *)[id2 objectAtIndex:row];

        NSLog(@"%@",currencyid2);
        NSLog([id2 objectAtIndex:row]);
    }
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&from_curr=%@&to_curr=%@&value=%@",branchid1,currencyid1,currencyid2,fourthstr];
[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];
```

Comment: Show me your code where you're passing param.?

Comment: You should be calling: "fourthstr = value1.text;", as "value1.text" is already a string.

Comment: its always string, why you need the another conversion

Comment: ya but that string not passing to the Post method @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: first of all log `value1.text`  value

Comment: Update your question with the "post method" you keep referring to.

Comment: ya updated my post method @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

// Text field text property always  gives string value

```
fourthstr =  value1.text;
```

Comment: i tried your code also but its showing empty value passing the method @Andey Satyanarayana

Comment: i think you forget to give iboutlet connection to textField from XIB

Comment: i given iboutlet connection but its showing zero@Andey Satyanarayana

Comment: constant value means its working @Andey Satyanarayana

Comment: put this line in- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

Comment: fourthstr =  value1.text;

Comment: it will work , you assign the value in viewdidload method it is not updated when you change value of textfield.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111621/discussion-between-a-sonu-and-andey-satyanarayana).

Comment: ya i putted but no change @Andey Satyanarayana

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code,

first assign the textfield value to string,

```
NSString *fourthstr = value1.text;
```

parameter assign is given below,

```
NSDictionary *queryParams = @{
                                  @"YourKeyValue"          : fourthstr,
                                  };
```

then the above param pass to post method, hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

value of value1.text will empty string (default value of UITextfield's text property @"") on viewdidload, you should use it when you pass it to the parameter for POST method.